# How do I reference object being initialized in the initializer with c#?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have an object initializer similar to the following:

```
var coolObject = new CoolObject()
{
    GetObjectState = () => coolObject.InternalState;
}
```

Where GetObjectState is a Function on CoolObject that returns some kind of object state. In this case, I'd like that function to simply return the coolObject's internal state object. The code object clearly won't compile because you can't reference a local variable before it's declared.

Is there a way around this? Is there something similar to the "this" keyword for initializers?

Comment: Do you have to use a constructor? Is there some reason why you can't just have a static property on `CoolObject` and use that for your assignments?

Comment: @wsanville Probably because different instances need different object states returned.

Comment: Is there a reason this isn't part of the constructor? That's part of the reason we have constructors that take arguments and do work.

Comment: Even if you move the func to the constructor, you have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
CoolObject coolObject = null;
coolObject = new CoolObject()
{
    GetObjectState = () => coolObject.InternalState;
}
```

Although this code is unsafe if the value of coolObject changes before it is called.

Comment: That'll compile, sure, but then won't my anonymous method point to an object with a null reference? It'll point to the first declaration of coolObject, which points to a null on the heap. Then when the second line runs, it'll create a new object on the heap, but my method will still point to the first, no?

Comment: @JonathanBeerhalter This is fine; the lambda closes over the *variable*, not the value of the variable. After the second line runs, the hoisted variable will refer to a non-null `CoolObject`. Still, this is a dangerous and unnecessary plan. Just refactor so you don't have to do this.

Comment: The anonymous method will point to coolObject, once it is executed it will figure out what the value of coolObject is. I don't remember what actually happens, but I believe classes are generated, one of which has a reference to coolObject, not the one sitting on the heap, but to what the value of coolObject currently sitting on the stack is.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich Yes, the local variable will be *hoisted* to a field on a compiler-generated class. Though it's still conceptually a local variable, it will no longer be stored on the stack at all (at least as far as the lambda is concerned.) The lambda will use whatever that field's value is, so this approach *does work* (though is brittle and confusing and should be discarded.)

Comment: @dlev I once had to go with something along these lines. I had sets of lambda, whose execution order was known. Two of them were created in a single method. I then had a variable in that method, that was captured by the first lambda, given a value, and then captured again by the second lambda and used. Turned out well, but would probably agree with you and recommend he not use it in this case.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with capturing variables. I just think it's unnecessary in this case, since the captured variable references an object that could probably be more sensibly (and safely) referred to by `this`.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just remove the {}, i.e. what is wrong with:

```
var coolObject = new CoolObject();
coolObject.GetObjectState = () => coolObject.InternalState;
```

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my comment: There's no reason to use this approach. You're almost certainly better off just defining `GetObjectState` as an actual method, rather than an `Func<TypeOfInternalState>`:

```
public TypeOfInternalState GetObjectState() { return this.InternalState }
```

And now there's no need for the compiler to hoist a local variable, and no weird construction syntax where you refer to a variable which references the object currently being constructed.

Comment: Right, but then you can't change how GetObjectState() executes at runtime. I can't call GetObjectState = {some code here}

Comment: I suppose, but that still seems like a very brittle approach. Making the method `virtual` and then overriding in a derived class does pretty much the same thing, except in safe and obvious way. I understand the thinking when you really do expect consumers of the class to specify behaviour (though even then it's usually done as an argument to the constructor which is set once) but given that your method is intended to retrieve the state of the object (a very private operation that really should only be done by the object itself) I contend that your method should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
public class CoolObject
{
    public CoolObject()
    {
        GetObjectState = () => this.InternalState;
    }

    public Func<InternalState> GetObjectState;
}
```

You can override to your heart's content and the default state works for most cases.